# Subgroups of the elementary abelian group $E_8$ (or is it?)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am computing the Galois group of $(x^2-2)(x^2-3)(x^2 -5)$. I found it to be:

$$G = \{1,a,b,c,ab,ac,bc,abc\}$$

where:

$$a: \begin{cases} \sqrt2 \to \sqrt 2 \\ \sqrt 3 \to \sqrt 3 \\ \sqrt 5 \to -\sqrt 5 \end{cases}, b:\begin{cases} \sqrt2 \to \sqrt 2 \\ \sqrt 3 \to -\sqrt 3 \\ \sqrt 5 \to \sqrt 5 \end{cases}, c:\begin{cases} \sqrt2 \to -\sqrt 2 \\ \sqrt 3 \to \sqrt 3 \\ \sqrt 5 \to \sqrt 5 \end{cases}$$

notice that $a^2=b^2=c^2 = 1$, that the group is commutative and that it is generated by $a,b,c$.

Hence, I found the subgroups to be:

$$1,\langle a\rangle, \langle b\rangle, \langle c \rangle, \langle ab\rangle, \langle ac\rangle, \langle bc\rangle, \langle abc \rangle, \langle a,b \rangle, \langle a,c \rangle, \langle b,c\rangle, \langle a,bc\rangle, \langle ab,c\rangle, \langle ac,b \rangle, G $$

these are $15$. Looking [at this page](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_8), I see that this group must be the elementary abelian group $E_8$. However, I am missing a subgroup (they should be $16$). Can someone point out to me what subgroup I am missing? I have been staring at this for too long, and I can't see what I am missing. Maybe I went wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As each finite Abelian group is self-dual, it has as many groups of order $d$ as of order $|G|/d$. You have seven subgroups of order two, but only six of order four. There is a subgroup of order four missing. It is
$\left<ab,ac\right>$.

Comment: I see why this is the missing subgroup, but I don't understand the first bit. Could you please explain?

Comment: The dual group of $G$, viz., $\widehat G=\text{Hom}(G,\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)$ is isomorphic to $G$. Subgroups of $G$ naturally correspond to quotient groups of $\widehat G$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really nice information.